# A Mars based movie where the mission crew discover ancient-advanced martian installation revealing humans are a product resulted of martian DNA?

Tags: story-identification, movie, mars

I've been trying to remember the name of a Mars based movie. The plot takes place in the near future when the first mars man mission just leaves the earth.

While inside the martian installation, the mission crew are revealed that humans are a product resulted of martian DNA left by the martians (to be seeded on earth) millions of years in the past right after they left their planet behind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for the 2000 movie [*Mission to Mars,*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0183523/) starring [Gary Sinise.](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000641/?ref_=tt_ov_st)

From the IMDB link:

> When the first manned mission to Mars meets with a catastrophic and
>   mysterious disaster after reporting a unidentified structure, a rescue
>   mission is launched to investigate the tragedy and bring back any
>   survivors.

The end of the movie involves the famous [Face of Mars,](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2001/ast24may_1/) which in the movie turns out to be an alien artifact.

Comment: [Prometheus](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1446714/) has a similar story, just not on Mars.

Comment: That's exactly the name of the movie! I've just flicked through the movie's poster on IMDB app, I couldn't recognized it though, not even by reading its description. Thanks!